# adal getCachedToken is always null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adal, adal.js

I would get cached token using react-adal api

```
import { authContext, } from '../auth'
const AvatarContainer = () => {
    getPersonPhoto(authContext)
    return (
        <Avatar />
    )
}
async function getPersonPhoto(authContext) {
    const user = await authContext.getCachedUser();
    const token = authContext.getCachedToken('https://graph.microsoft.com')
    console.log("the token", token)
    var photoUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + user.profile.aud + "/photo/$value";
    var Avatar = null;
    // try {
    //     Avatar = await client
    //         .api(photoUrl)
    //         .get();
    //     return Avatar;
    // } catch (e) { return null; }
}
export default AvatarContainer
```

The token value is **always null**, I have specified the `ressource uri`but it's not working.

I checked my localstorage I have the token

Comment: Can you provide your authContext` code that should, presumably, fetching token from local storage and providing it to the app?

Comment: It's an instance of  adal `AuthenticationContext` class https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/Config-authentication-context

Comment: So are you sure you have a valid user? Can you verify that `user` is not null as well?

Comment: yes I'm well loggedin

Comment: This might be interesting: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/742

Answer (score 0):

You might try [opening an issue in Github](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues), or upgrading to [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) now that ADAL is being deprecated.